# how can i wait for firebase to check the user is valid before sending a POST request with reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using the following code to obtain the users idToken before sending it to the backend as an authorisation header:

```
const user = firebase.auth().currentUser
const idToken = await user.getIdToken()
```

sent like this:

```
var res = await axios.post(backUrl + "account/load_balance", { 
uid: uid, 
id: id 
},
{
  headers: {
  Authorization: 'Bearer ' + idToken
   }});
```

It works well but on one of my pages the request is sent to the server before idtoken variable has filled and the user is still null.

I have read that i need to implement onAuthStateChanged as it waits for the token before triggering: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#web-version-8

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in, see docs for a list of available properties
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User
    var uid = user.uid;
    // ...
  } else {
    // User is signed out
    // ...
  }
});
```

However i am unsure how to implement this in to my code.
Can anyone advise?

Full code:

```
const RoutingForPortfolio = (props) => {

    let uid = localStorage.getItem("account-info");
    let { id } = useParams();

    const loadBlockchainData = async (dispatch) => {

        if (id === null || id === undefined) {
            id = "test";
        }
        
        const user = firebase.auth().currentUser
        const idToken = await user.getIdToken()
        console.log(idToken)
        var res = await axios.post(backUrl + "account/load_balance", { 
        uid: uid, 
        id: id 
        },
        {
          headers: {
          Authorization: 'Bearer ' + idToken
           }});
        if (res.data === null) {
            await wait(2);
            document.location.href = "/logout"
            return;
        }
        else {
            // const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://data.stocksfc.com:3200'));
            // dispatch(web3Loaded(web3));
            const account = res.data.address;
            dispatch(web3AccountLoaded(account));
            localStorage.setItem("account-address", account);
            if (res.data.token_flag && res.data.exchange_flag) {
                await dispatch(setLoginUserName(res.data.name));
                await dispatch(setLoginUserEmail(res.data.email));
                if (res.data.balance !== null) {
                    await dispatch(etherBalanceLoaded(res.data.balance[0]));
                    await dispatch(tokenBalanceLoaded(res.data.balance[1]));
                    await dispatch(exchangeEtherBalanceLoaded(res.data.balance[2]));
                    await dispatch(exchangeTokenBalanceLoaded(res.data.balance[3]));
                }
            }
            else {
                Swal.fire({
                    icon: "error",
                    title: "Error...",
                    text: "Error 485 - Please report to admin",
                });
                return;
            }
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        if (uid) {
            loadBlockchainData(props.dispatch);
        }
    }, [props.dispatch, uid]);

    return (
        <>
            {uid ? (
                <div>
                    <Portfolio id={id} />
                </div>
            ) : (
                <Login />
            )}
        </>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you correctly identified, `firebase.auth().currentUser` is a synchronous action that only gets the user object when it is called. You've also correctly surmised that you instead need to use `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged()` to wait to check if the user is logged in.

This can be achieved by wrapping an `onAuthStateChanged` listener into a `Promise` where it is immediately detached after being called once.

```
function getValidatedUser() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const unsubscribe = firebase.auth()
      .onAuthStateChanged(
        (user) => {
          unsubscribe();
          resolve(user);
        },
        reject // pass up any errors attaching the listener
      );
  });
}
```

This now allows you to use:

```
const user = await getValidatedUser();
if (!user) {
  // todo: handle no user signed in, such as:
  throw new Error("User not signed in!");
}

// if here, user is User object
const idToken = await user.getIdToken()
```