# How to return the data of an async function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, asynchronous, async-await

I can't seem to figure out how to return the data so I can use it as a react component from my asynchronous function. I lack the understanding of how to get my data from the promise or async function to a normal function that I can call for a component since I know you cannot return things to a component from an asynchronous function.

Can someone please guide me in the right direction? After assigning the data to a UserProfile object, I want to display the hobbies attribute.

Heres my relevant code

```
class UserProfile{
    constructor(hobbies) {
        this.hobbies = hobbies;
    }
}

const userProfileConverter = {
    toFirestore: (UserProfile) => {
        return {
            hobbies: UserProfile.hobbies
        }
    },
    fromFirestore: (snapshot, options) => {
        const data = snapshot.data(options);
        return new UserProfile(data.hobbies);
    }
}

export const GetUserProfile = async () => {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject){
        onAuthStateChanged(auth, async (user) => {
            if (user) {
                console.log('Reached this point!')
                const uid = user.uid;
                console.log('uid: ', uid);
                // const docRef = doc(db, "users", "profile", "hobbies", uid)
                const docRef = doc(db, "users", uid, "profile", "hobbies").withConverter(userProfileConverter);
                const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);
                if (docSnap.exists()) {
                    const userProfile = docSnap.data();
                    console.log('data: ', docSnap.data());
                    console.log('User Profile obj data: ', userProfile)
                    resolve(userProfile);
                }
            } else {
                console.error('No signed in user!')
                reject('No signed in user.');
            }
        })
    })

}

const displayUserProfile = () => {
    GetUserProfile().then((userProfile) => {
        return(
            <>
                <h1>
                    {userProfile.hobbies}
                </h1>
            </>
        );
    });
}

export default displayUserProfile;
```

I've tried returning from within the onauthstatechanged in the GetUserProfile function (which I know is bad practice) and from the promise but just can't seem to figure how how to get the data outside of a promise or async function so I can use it.

Comment: You've missed the `return` at the start of the `GetUserProfile().then((userProfile) => {` line. Alternatively, you can take @itsdaniel0's approach and use `async`/`await`. Additionally, you should make sure to remove the `onAuthStateChanged` listener when you are done with it as shown in [this `getValidatedUser()` method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73631198/3068190).

Answer (score 1):

You need to await it

```js
const displayUserProfile = async () => {
    const userProfile = await GetUserProfile();
    return(
        <>
            <h1>
                {userProfile.hobbies}
            </h1>
        </>
    );
}
```